# Is the tag wiki retained for a tag that gets removed for having no entries?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

If a tag wiki becomes inaccessible due to a tag being eliminated, is the data destroyed? Or would it be able to be recovered by just recreating the tag?

On Gaming we had one tag for a particularly difficult case that a wiki entry was written for. There has been some debate as to what we should keep the tag as, which has led to the only instance of the tag being renamed a few times and eventually left on a new tag. The nightly script eventually cleaned out the original tag, and the wiki is inaccessible. So would I be able to retrieve this by reverting to the original tag, or is a rewrite of the wiki necessary?

Comment: This could also happen easily when tags are merged.

Comment: @Andrew what has been completed? It's a support question. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Erk. I didn't even realize that. I guess I just saw that waffles' answer was accepted. I'll let Grace Note ping me if she wants that to be considered a proper tag, and perhaps adding something to the question to make the answer appear to be 'correct'. OR something! hehe

Comment: @Andrew cough... Grace is a diamond mod as well, with powers beyond our imagination (aka CM) so he/she can do it as well. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm just going to go sit in a corner now. ;-) Anybody have a dunce cap?!?!?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the tag count goes 0 we will end up with an orphan Post of type wiki, I plan to add a report to the mod window which will help find these.

As with all posts on the site, we only soft delete now.

Comment: Maybe it's not so fine for the merge victims, but for my scenario it's fine. It's an easy rewrite, it was mostly on curiosity I asked.

Comment: Now that we have apparently [migrated to the new post type](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62898/this-tag-has-no-tag-wiki-but-wait-wiki-not-found-by-preview/62905#62905 "At least, it is implied here that we are now in the new post type"), care to update your answer with what currently happens to the wiki when a tag goes 0 count?

Comment: @Grace, done ...

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote and accept if I hadn't already done so, so I'll instead upvote the related posts about the new post type. Thanks again!

Comment: Do these just linger? Can we get a denormalised field in there showing what the wiki belonged to before it was cast into the cold rain on the footsteps of Our Holy Mother of Mercy?