# Provide an option to migrate tag wikis with a synonym creation

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki, moderator-abilities

On [rpg](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com) we recently migrated all our `dd*` tags to `dnd*`.  When we did this we obviously created tag synonyms to keep them from re-appearing. However when we did so, we lost all our tag wikis that were associated with those tags.  Please add a feature to allow for merging or copying of tag wiki's when doing this work.  Or at least a warning about tag wikis on the page.

Comment: According to [waffles over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62536/is-the-tag-wiki-retained-for-a-tag-that-gets-removed-for-having-no-entries/62586#62586), there is an orphan wiki that diamonds will be able to access in order to retrieve the old wikis. It does not look like it is quite available yet, though.