# Is it possible to rescue an orphaned tag wiki?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

A while ago, I wrote a tag wiki for the [dsp] tag on SO.  Later, [dsp] became a synonym for [signal-processing].  However, nobody has written a tag wiki for the latter.  Is there any way to retrieve the text of the [dsp] wiki and transfer it to [signal-processing]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! Well, you might not necessarily be able to do it directly yourself. But 10k users have access to a new feature in their tools which lets them see wiki posts. Wikis for tags which get eradicated end up as "orphan wikis". These users can read those wikis and then collect the text contained within.

However, there are two things to note:

1. This wasn't immediately available when tag wikis were first established. So if it is a particularly old wiki (like what happened [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62536/is-the-tag-wiki-retained-for-a-tag-that-gets-removed-for-having-no-entries)), then there is no orphan.
2. There is no visual indication of what tag any particular orphan wiki is for. So it may take some time for someone to find the right one. If you can remember the date you created the wiki, then it can help as the entries in the tool are listed in reverse chronological order.

As an example, [this is the orphan wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/63199/revisions) for the old [always-friday-in-iceland](/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland), which became a synonym for [fun](/questions/tagged/fun). No guarantees on the visibility of that link, though, but if it's anything like the FAQ revision history then anyone can look at it.

Comment: Visibility of post 63199 revisions is completely public (I logged out and tried it).

Comment: Ah, nicely. Thanks for the confirmation, @Jon.

Comment: @Grace - Well, I think I wrote it around May or June.  But I'm not really sure.  I guess I'll just rewrite it, I'm a long long way from 10k.  Thanks.

Comment: @mtrw You don't have to wait until reaching 10k. A 10k Stack Overflow user may be able to help you. Try poking into Chat to see if anyone is around that can help, and give them the details necessary to identify the wiki.

Comment: On which page do those orphaned wikis show up?

Comment: @sth tools → links → recent wikis created. It is going to be very cumbersome on a site like Stack Overflow... but it's the best we have.

Comment: @Grace Note: Would there be some indication if a particular wiki is orphaned, because I can't see anything like that? Also that list seems to be limited to 15 pages, so on SO no wikis created before the end of September can be found this way... :(

Comment: @sth Orphaned wikis state "orphan wiki". It's easy to see what is an orphan wiki, but not to see what tag it originally represented. I'm a bit surprised about the page limit, as I expected it would be like recently deleted/closed, which extend the full history.

Comment: @Grace Note: Ah, now I see, I found one. Sadly for the OP it's not the former [dsp] wiki, and because of the page limit I can't look further in the past. The list would really be more useful if it was unlimited like the deleted/closed lists.