# Should I reject tag wiki excerpts based on tag itself?

Tags: support, tags, review, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I'm currently reviewing (or I was, considering SO is a fast moving place) a tag wiki excerpt for [interface-inheritance](/questions/tagged/interface-inheritance). In my opinion, this tag should never exist in the first place. Just using the tags [interface](/questions/tagged/interface) and [inheritance](/questions/tagged/inheritance) should be enough. The tag has 0 followers and has been used 11 times.

Should I reject the Wiki excerpt? Should I take other steps for the tag to be removed? Or should I just skip and leave it be?

Comment: Tags in post won't work of course, just used for highlighting.

Comment: Well, following my answer [on this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228902/if-i-produce-a-zombie-tag-by-retagging-should-i-leave-a-hint-on-tag-excerpt), I'd say if the tag should be removed then it's pointless to have a wiki, so reject it explaining why.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd do: reject with custom message: *This tag is useless, no point in adding a wiki.*

Comment: I've done exactly that for now (it resurfaced in the review queue), hoping for some more definitive answer - if that can be given anyway.

Comment: I've burninated the tag. The [tag excerpt suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5017816) is still active, the [suggested edit on the wiki itself was rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5017815).

Comment: And the excerpt suggestion squeaked through on a 3 to 2 vote.

Comment: OK, at least I now know what to do :) Anybody for creating an "official" answer?

Comment: @owlstead since you asked so nicely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is that you, as power user, think the tag is useless to begin with.

In such case, removing the tag is in order and my answer to [If I produce a Zombie Tag by retagging, should I leave a hint on tag excerpt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228902/if-i-produce-a-zombie-tag-by-retagging-should-i-leave-a-hint-on-tag-excerpt) applies in your case as well:

> this (creating a wiki) will be pointless for the simple reason that each new tag (no matter if it appeared before or not) gets whole new ID number behind the scenes and whole new wiki

So to sum it up: yes, you should reject such edit, better with a custom reason explaining why.